# a program in memory and its memory mapping

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am getting a bit confused for the address space mappings of a program in memory,
here is a link
http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory
it deals with virtual address mapping of program in executing and has marked 1GB for kernel mode and 3 GB for user mode,
and mentions use of page tables for access to memory segments,

Linux uses a page file which is 4 KB only on x86 architectures if I am not wrong then how does a process can use 3GB of mapped address space from memory (as given on link that each process is of 4GB ).This is a bit counter intuitive to me or my understanding is wrong some where?

Comment: Linux uses a **page** of size 4kB...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you right or not. It seems you think the processor uses 4KB page to manage the mapped file.

In fact, this 4KB is just a page memory buffer. When system tries to read data from any file to memory, it will firstly read the content inside the page memory buffer and move the content in the buffer to the real stack or heap later. This 4KB page buffer is not used to control mapped memory address.

The mapped address is something like HANDLE, I think. It stores in one part of memory. When you use this handle to get data, the system will count and transfer it to real address on DISK. Then system will read mapped data to page buffer and finally move them to the memory.

The details, please check following link:
http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files
This blog also has several other good articles about memory management. Complicated but really nice.